# What does it means "specimen centered result reporting" and "order centered result reporting" on IHE technical framework?

Tags: hl7

[IHE](http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks/#laboratory) Technical framework for Pathology and Laboratory uses  "specimen centered result reporting" and "order centered result reporting" a lot pointing what is `OUL^R22` & `ORU^R01` from HL7 meant for. I don't understand what does it actually means, what is different one from other and how is it useful each one.

Answer (score 0):

HL7

Specimen Oriented [OUL^R22]

This message was designed to accommodate specimen oriented testing. It should be applicable to container-less testing (e.g., elephant on a table) and laboratory automation systems requiring container.

Generally this construct allows transfer of multiple results related to a specimen from a patient, where this specimen has been in none, one, or multiple containers.
In addition to the patient results themselves it permits the communication of the following kinds of information:
Analysis results of a non patient related sample (e.g., environmental) - patient related segments (e.g., PID, PD1, PV1, PV2) are optional.
Analysis results to a particular container with QC sample and the lot and manufacturer information about this sample (SAC-INV segments) - however for this purpose the “Unsolicited Specimen Container Oriented Observation Message” (OUL^R23) is recommended due to explicit relation between the observation and the container.
Basic identification data (lot, manufacturer, etc.) of the reagents and other substances involved in the generation of analysis results (TCD-SID segments).

Order Oriented [OUL^R24]

This message was designed to accommodate multi-specimen oriented testing. It should be applicable to, e.g., laboratory automation systems requiring containers.

Generally this construct allows transfer of multiple results, each one related to none, one or more specific containers with one or more specimens for a patient. (Example: Creatinine Clearance results with detailed information about the urine and serum specimens and their containers.)

In addition to patient results themselves it permits the communication of the following kind of information:

Analysis results of a non patient related sample (e.g. environmental) - patient related segments (e.g. PID, PD1, PV1, PV2) are optionals.
Analysis results to a particular container with QC, sample and the lot and manufacturer information about this sample (SAC-INV segments).
Basic identification data (lot, manufacturer, etc) of the reagents and other substances involved in the generation of analysis results (TCD-SID segments)

References

HL7 Messaging v2.5.1: Chapter 7 /21

Clinical Laboratory Automation: HL7 v2.5.1: Chapter 13